# Select2 shows undefined when using multiple false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following fiddle that shows a select2 that is pre-populated: http://jsfiddle.net/EHzcc/465/

The code is as follows:

```
$('#Test').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: "AJAX/Thing.ashx",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                searchTerm: params,
                requestName: "GetSelect2",
                entity: entity,
                field: fieldName,
                textField: fieldTextName,
                schema: schema
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data };
        },
        cache: false
    }
});

var initData = [{ 'id' : 1, 'text' : 'Hello World' }];

$('#Test').select2('data', initData);
```

But as you will see, the select2 shows `undefined` as the selected option.

However if I set the multiple to true, it works...  see here: http://jsfiddle.net/EHzcc/466/

How can I make it work for multiple false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are forgetting brackets and a colon instead of a comma

```
$('#Test').select2({'data':initData});
```

Link see the placeholders as an example,
https://select2.github.io/examples.html#placeholders

Comment: Wow... that works, but it's strange how mine worked for the multiple true, so both are valid, but yours is the one needed for the multiple false to work... Thanks.

Comment: i was confused aswell why yours was working hehe. i dont now why you have data in quotes since it is not necesary according to the DOC's. anyway Good luck.

Comment: Ah, actually it doesn't work, as it then breaks the AJAX stuff, as it looks like by using the `{}` brackets, we overwrite the settings. If I try to just add all the other settings as well, then it calls the AJAX stuff on load which also breaks it as it then overwrites the preload data as there is no searchTerm passed.

Comment: maybe you can use javascript array index? I see that if you use initData[0] it will work. i dont now how exactly the library works but maybe this can help you?.

Comment: You are a legend! `initData[0]` works perfect :) Thanks!